# Sum query in sequalizze?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

it is very simple to code sum query in raw querys but i am using sequelize and i didn't find any way to do so suppose i have an table named "fruits" and it contain following data

**name:-** *apple, mango, strawberry*

**qty:-** *20, 50, 30*

and i want to know the total qty of all fruits i tried hard but dont get any useful result here is the code which i try :-

```
fruits.find({}).sum('qty').done(function (err, totalQty) {
        if(err){
           console.log(err)
        }
        console.lof(totalQty)
    })
```

please help me out ...

Comment: have you tried group: ['name'] inside find{}  ?

Comment: TypeError: fruits.find(...).sum is not a function

Comment: i just got the error nothing else

Comment: in this case your expected value is 100?

Comment: yes exectly i want total qty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fruits.sum('qty').then(function (totalQty) {

        console.log(totalQty)
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: it just group all the same fruits but i need the total of their qty

Comment: i got an error:-     Executing (default): SELECT sum(`qty`) AS `qty` FROM `fruits` AS `fruits`;
746640
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 746640

Comment: @AliAsgherBadshah yeah so it looks like your totalQty is 746640 . but the other error is not related to this question. its another bug.

Comment: @AliAsgherBadshah I don't know what's ur fruits sequelize object look like and also 746640 is not a status code . it prints 746640 before the eror which means your console.log(totalQty) printed 746640. if u are not sure you can do console.log('total is: ', totalQty)

Comment: thx it work i done somw mistake in writting code thx alot for your help you solved my problem  :)